How to make a reversal of sample curve node
I have a vector (XYZ coordinates from the hit position of a ray-cast node) that is more or less on it, but not perfectly (because for the raycast i had to use curve to mesh). I need to get the factor (or the length, both are good) that if i were to place a point on it would be the closest one to that other coordinate vector.
I basically need the reversed functionality of the "Sample Curve" node, meaning i want to put, what now is outputted, a vector (coordinates) and i want it to output, what is now inputted, the factor & length values.
Is there anything like that possible, without any "curve to mesh" workarounds?
Here's the blend file 

Hello and welcome  Its_Gerryz, it would be helpfull if you post your .blend here:
https://blend-exchange.com/

just to understand you right: you want the curve fac/length to be the nearest point to a position, right?

Ouch, I ask for it and I have it. I meant a simplify version of your .blend that highlights your problem. Never the less, a reverse Sample Curve could be  a Set Spline Type on Bézier plug on a Set Handle Type on auto. Even with a low resolution the incoming curve is very near the original… If it’s work for you? The .blend:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/5XPDV1J3/

For Chris, yes! Exactly!
Also for Fred, Altho this looks like a simple solution, would it be possible for you to explain how it is supposed to work? If i plug everything correctly, how would it work? What purpose does each node serve?

By default a Curve is set on Poly after a Mesh to Curve so you have to set it back to Bézier in order to recover something near the original Curve. It’s only near because it’s keeping all the points of the Mesh then the Set Handle Type on Auto will recalculate the curve position “correctly” except for the extremities. Of course if you need to have just 2 control points it will not work (because there is many from the Mesh) but if just to measure with Factor it will be fine (really near exact).
